# How to replace a href link of a specific web using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, replace

I have many links from the same web but with different dirreciones

```
<a href="somelink.com/1" title="this link">
</a>
<a href="somelink.com/2" title="this link">
</a>
<a href="somelink.com/3" title="this link">
</a>
<a href="somelink.com/3" title="this link">
</a>
```

He tried to use the code but it does not work for me since he searches for a specific url and not all

```
var a = document.querySelector('a[href="somelink.com"]');
if (a) {
  a.setAttribute('href', 'replacedlink.com')
}
<a href="somelink.com" title="this link">
</a>
```

How could I do it in a massive way and do it to all the url of a web site in estecifico for example: somelink.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Syntax) `^=` to check if the href starts with `somelink.com`. Then you could replace the url :

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="somelink.com"]').forEach(
  x => x.href = x.href.replace("somelink.com", "replacedlink.com")
);
```

```html
<a href="somelink.com/1" title="this link">a
</a>
<a href="somelink.com/2" title="this link">b
</a>
<a href="somelink.com/3" title="this link">c
</a>
<a href="somelink.com/3" title="this link">d
</a>
<a href="otherlink.com/3" title="this link">e
</a>
```

If you want to replace the whole link, you could set the href attribute to the new link:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="somelink.com"]').forEach(
  x => x.href = "replacedlink.com"
)
```

```html
<a href="somelink.com/1" title="this link">a
</a>
<a href="somelink.com/2" title="this link">b
</a>
<a href="somelink.com/3" title="this link">c
</a>
<a href="somelink.com/3" title="this link">d
</a>
<a href="otherlink.com/3" title="this link">e
</a>
```

Comment: thanks, but how would you replace the whole url osea somelink.com/1 -> replacedlink.com, removing the parameter / 1

Comment: @juan In that case you can set the href attribute to the new link. I have updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try adding class to the links and then use get element by class and replace the link
       <a href="www.google.com" class="abc">my url</a>
        var i=document.getElementByClass("abc");
          for(let j=0;j<i.length;j++){
           i[j].href='newUrl';
            }
```

Comment: in my case the url have no class, they are stored in a database

Comment: then u can concat the url on  click like if u have base url www.facebook.com and you want to go to setting page y can add the value on click so the url becomes www.facebook.com/settings

Answer (score 0):

For multiple items we can replace this way:

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('.your_attr_class').forEach( (item)=>{ 

      if(item.href.startsWith('http://somelink.com')){
        item.href.replace('http://somelink.com','http://replacewith.com');
      }

});
```

Comment: I do not work, my friend, because the urls have parameters

Comment: You can check the href with startsWith method and then can replace as you want.